# How to pass ENV values dynamically in docker file while running docker run command?

Tags: docker

I gave the below content in docker file

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
ENV value = $var_anme
ENTRYPOINT  ["/bin/bash", "-c", "echo hello, $value"]
```

and after image build I gave below command

```
docker run -it test:latest -e var_name="welcome"
```

I got output as

```
hello, =
```

Expected output is

```
hello,welcome
```

I don't know what mistake I did can someone explain me please

Comment: The output you get should give you a hint about where the problem is. Read about the [`ENV` command](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#env)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that you are trying to provide a value at runtime for something that has been set during build time.

In your `Dockerfile` you are setting the variable `value` to `$var_name`. This instruction is evaluated during the building phase of the docker image (i.e. when you issue `docker build -t test .`.

At this stage the environment variable `var_name` is not populated, so during the building phase docker will create an image with the `value` environment variable set to empty.

What you need to do is to provide a value for your `value` variable to the container you are creating. You do this by specifying by issuing a run command like the following:

`docker run -e value=welcome test`

What is usually done is to use the `ENV` directive in a `Dockerfile` to set some default value for the variables your program will be using and then overwriting them when you create the container to customize their value.

Adapting your example:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
ENV value=Andrea 
ENTRYPOINT  ["/bin/bash", "-c", "echo hello, $value"]
```

The command `docker run test` would output `hello, Andrea`.

The command `docker run -e value=John test` would output `hello, John`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is what you want to achieve, but if you have the option to set the environment variable at build-time (rather than at runtime) you can try this one:

Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
ARG VALUE="not_set"
ENV value=${VALUE}

ENTRYPOINT  ["/bin/bash", "-c", "echo hello, $value"]
```

Building the image:

```
docker build --build-arg VALUE="World" -t test:latest .
```

Running the container:

```
docker run -it test:latest
```

Maybe this helps.
Edit: Actually, @nivox explanation is pretty neat :D

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues in your `Dockerfile` and the way you start the container.

As you can see from the documentation of the [`ENV` command](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#env) it has two forms:

```
ENV <key> <value>
ENV <key>=<value> ...
```

In the first form, the variable's name and value are separated by spaces. From the output you posted I suspect that only the first word of `<value>` is used; if `<value>` contains white spaces you have to wrap it into quotes.

The second form uses `=` to separate the name and the value but there must be no spaces around the equal sign.

Given the way you use `ENV`, Docker thinks you want to use the first form and assigns the value `=` to the environment variable `value`.

There is a typo on the value you want to use to initialize `value`. In the `Dockerfile` it is named `var_anme` then in the command line you use `var_name`.

`$var_anme` is not initialized and it is also not declared as being initialized from outside. Depending when you want to set it, a variable that is initialized from outside the `Dockerfile` must be declared using [`ARG`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#arg) or [`ENV`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#env).

```
docker run -it test:latest -e var_name="welcome"
```

There are two issues in the command line. First, the options (`-e`) stay before the image name. Everything after the image name is the command to run inside the container.

Then, `-e var_name="welcome"` sets an environment variable named `var_name` but the image does not expect any variable with this name. It declares and expects a variable named `value`.

All in all, the `Dockerfile` should read:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
ENV value=world
ENTRYPOINT  ["/bin/bash", "-c", "echo hello, $value"]
```

The line `ENV value=world` provides a default value for the environment variable `value` but a different value can be assigned to it from outside by using `-e` in the command line:

```
docker run -it -e value="welcome" test:latest
```

See it in action:

```
$ docker run --rm -it test:latest
hello, world
$ docker run --rm -it -e value=welcome test:latest
hello, welcome
```